# Running AzureML experiment programatically with data, error loading data

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

I am following [this](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/work-with-data/datasets-tutorial/scriptrun-with-data-input-output/how-to-use-scriptrun.ipynb) tutorial to send a script to AzureML.

Getting an error on the last line of the step that loads data:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace

ws = Workspace.get(name="ws_name", subscription_id='asdfadsfasdf232323', resource_group='my-rg')

def_blob_store = ws.get_default_datastore()
def_blob_store.upload_files(files = ['dummy_file.pkl'],
                       target_path = 'script-run/',
                       overwrite = True,
                       show_progress = True)

def_blob_store = ws.get_default_datastore()
input_data = Dataset.File.from_files(def_blob_store.path('script-run/dummy_file.pkl')).as_named_input('input').as_mount()
```

The error I get:

> ImportError: Missing required package "azureml-dataset-runtime", which can be installed by running: "env_name\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install azureml-dataset-runtime --upgrade

I'm using pipenv and installed azureml-core using the pipenv install command.  I have seen that the AzureML library doesn't seem to play so well with pipenv.  I did try to install as per the message above but still getting the same error.  Tried

```
import azureml.datasets.runtime
```

But that doesn't work.  Running this on Python 3.9.6.

By the way, at this point, I don't care so much whether I load the file from the script or access it from the Data section of AzureML. I already have this same file loaded there, so a method to access it in the ScriptRunConfig step would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to access the input file in the ScriptRunConfig step is by keeping the file in your source directory with your script and access as root file.

[image]
[image]

Then you can use the `source directory` path for your file
[image]

With this I was able to execute the job.
[image]
For other details, you can also check this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553868/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-training-script-in-azure-machine-learning-service)

Comment: So this works.  The downside is that I need to upload the data every time I run the script, so would be good to understand how to upload it once or refer to it once I already have in the AzureML environment.